# Преобразование массива с объектами в новый объект?

Tags: javascript, map-reduce

Как преобразовать массив

```
let myArr = [{
    name: "width",
    value: 100
}, {
    name: "height",
    value: 40
}];
```

в объект

```
let obj = {
    width: 100,
    height: 40
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) в помощь.

```js
const myArr = [{
    name: "width",
    value: 100
}, {
    name: "height",
    value: 40
}];

const res = myArr.reduce((obj, item) => {
  return Object.assign(obj, {[item.name]: item.value});
}, {});

console.log(res);
```