# Javascript: Как посчитать сколько раз встречается каждый символ в строке?

Tags: javascript

Как создать функцию, которая принимает один аргумент -  строку и возвращает объект, в котором указывается, сколько раз встречается каждый символ в переданной строке.

Например,

```
function countChars("aabbaccd") {

// код

}
```

должна вернуть объект типа `{a: 3, b: 2, c:2, d: 1}`

Comment: и где ваши попытки?)

Comment: PD https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320253/is-there-a-javascript-function-similar-to-the-python-counter-function

Comment: @ThisMan может, это нам задание

Comment: Вам уже рассказали про `reduce` - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1029758/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82

Comment: Не знаю, как подобраться к этому заданию

Comment: `str.split("").reduce(...)`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Оптимизация замены символа в строке на число его повторений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1040513/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9)

Comment: В таких случаях нужно описывать, что вы пробовали, чтобы было видно, что вы старались.

Comment: Извините, не знал, что такой формат обязателен. Спасибо, учту.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function countChars_long(str) {
  var result = {};
  var chars = str.split("");
  for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    var count = result[chars[i]]? result[chars[i]] : 0;
    result[chars[i]] = count + 1; 
  }
  return result;
}

function countChars_short(str) {
  return str.split("").reduce((r, c) => (r[c] = (r[c] || 0) + 1, r), {});
}

console.log(countChars_long("aabbaccd"));
console.log(countChars_short("aabbaccd"));
```

Comment: Зачем вы написали решение? Видно же, что это студент, он даже не написал, что как-то пытался выполнить это задание.

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться, как он работает, чтобы понять полностью

Comment: @Leks более или менее. Я добавил длинный вариант.